# Prove an alternating sequence is null

Tags: sequences-and-series

What's the cleanest way of proving that a sequence with different rules for odd and even terms (which are both null) is in totality null

So if n is even Xn = 1/n+1 if n is odd Xn = 1/n^3

Thanks

Comment: What's the question?  If you can show that the odd terms converge to a limit $L$ and that the even terms also converge to $L$, then that implies that the entire sequence converges to $L$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Please use mathjax or braces at the even subsequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ 0\leq X_n \leq \frac 1 n$ for all $n$. By Squeeze Theorem $\lim X_n =0$.